# Need to get id attribute

Tags: php, jquery

I have this php code to populate with links:

```
foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $result) 
        {
            if($result['tip']=='1')
            {
            $camere=" - ".$result['camere'];
            }
            else
            {
            $camere="";
            }
            $view[]="
            <tr>
            <td>".$result['id_anunt']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_tranzactie']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_prop'].$camere."</td>
            <td>".$result['judet']." ".$result['oras']." ".$result['zona']."</td>
            <td><a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'  onclick='view();'>View</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'>Edit</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'>Arhivare</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'>special</a></td>

            </tr>";

        }
```

I need to get the id attribute for "View" link on click it with this function:

```
function view()
            {
        alert ($(this).prop('id'));


    }
```

but I receive this: "object HTMLinputelemnt".
How can I get the id?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Weird... [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) returns `String` or `Boolean`, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your

```
onclick='view();'
```

to

```
onclick='view(this);'
```

And the view function as

```
function view(link)
        {
    alert ($(link).attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a Class on your link.

Eg:

```
<a href="#" class="viewLink" id="....
```

Then in jquery:

```
$(".viewLink").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: This script work but I have a separate file with js scripts and the page with inputs is called by ajax...so if I put this script in that other file will not working..so I need an alternative way (I need a function at onclick event)

Comment: Add the code in a `script` tag in your called ajax page. Or put the above code in your JS file, but change the click function to `$(".viewLink").on('click', function(){`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$view[]="
            <tr>
            <td>".$result['id_anunt']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_tranzactie']."</td>
            <td>".$result['den_prop'].$camere."</td>
            <td>".$result['judet']." ".$result['oras']." ".$result['zona']."</td>
            <td><a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'  onclick='return view(this);'>View</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'>Edit</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'>Arhivare</a> <a href='#' id='".$result['id_anunt']."'>special</a></td>

            </tr>";
```

Javascript

```
      function view(element){
        alert (element.id);
        return false;    
      }
```

OR

```
      alert ($(link).attr('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass the link object as a parameter to `view()`, like this: `onclick='view(this);'`

Then in pure javascript:

```
function view(el)
  {
  alert(el.id);
  }
```

*"Don't use a canon to kill a mosquito". -- Confucius*

Comment: How did this get an upvote?  Yes, `this.id` is better than creating a jQuery object and parsing its properties, but `this` is still not the link that was clicked so this won't work!

Comment: What Archer says. geomagas this would only be the case if you use an event handler ( like $.on() ), but if you use the onclick atrribute the `this` would be just the window object, I think.


EDIT: Yup. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7tQe/)

Comment: You're both right, edited my answer. _The "fingers faster than brain" syndrome again..._